# Complicated Django Query

Tags: python, django

My hodgepodge application's queries are going beyond my knowledge of how Django's ORM works.

Here's my current (incorrect) attempt:

```
queryset = Mentor.objects.filter(
    shift__session = session,
    jobs_desired = job
).exclude(
    shift__session = session,
    shift__jobs__time = job.time
)
```

My models are below if you want to read through them.

The initial `filter()` works fine. My issue is the `exclude()` chained onto the end.

The `exclude()` seems to be excluding `Mentor`s with:

- an associated `Shift` which meets the conditions specified
  (`shift__session = session`),
- AND a (possibly different) associated `Shift` that meets the second set of criteria `shift__jobs__time = job.time`.

I only want to filter out `Mentor`s that have a `Shift` associated with them that meets BOTH the criterion.

Any ideas?

```
class DojoSession(models.Model):
    term = models.ForeignKey(DojoTerm, help_text = "Dojo Term")
    date = models.DateField(
        blank = False,
        help_text = "Date during which the session will take place."
    )

    start = models.TimeField(
        blank = False,
        help_text = "Start Time"
    )

    end = models.TimeField(
        blank = False,
        help_text = "End Time"
    )

    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(
        Room,
        blank = True,
        help_text = "The rooms in which this session will be running."
    )

class Shift(models.Model):
    mentor = models.ForeignKey(
        'mentors.Mentor',
        blank = False,
        help_text = 'The mentor unergoing this shift.'
    )

    session = models.ForeignKey(
        DojoSession,
        blank = False,
        help_text = 'The session during which this shift takes place.',
    )

    role = models.ForeignKey(
        'mentors.Role',
        blank = False,
        help_text = "The role that the mentor will be undertaking during this shift.",
    )

    room = models.ForeignKey(
        Room,
        blank = True,
        null = True,
        help_text = "The room, if any, that the mentor will be undertaking the shift in."
    )

    jobs = models.ManyToManyField(
        'jobs.Job',
        blank = True,
        null = True,
    )

    start = models.TimeField(
        blank = False,
        help_text = "Start Time"
    )

    end = models.TimeField(
        blank = False,
        help_text = "End Time"
    )

class Job(models.Model):
    BEFORE = 'B'
    DURING = 'D'
    AFTER = 'A'

    TIME_CHOICES = (
        (BEFORE, 'Before session'),
        (DURING, 'During session'),
        (AFTER, 'After session'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length = 50,
        help_text = "The job's name."
    )

    description = models.TextField(
        max_length = 1024,
        help_text = "A description of the job."
    )

    location = models.CharField(
        max_length = 50,
        help_text = "The job's location."
    )

    time = models.CharField(
        max_length = 1,
        choices = TIME_CHOICES,
        help_text = "The time during a session at which this job can be carried out."
    )

class Mentor(models.Model):
    MALE_SMALL = "MS"
    MALE_MEDIUM = "MM"
    MALE_LARGE = "ML"
    MALE_EXTRA_LARGE = "MXL"

    FEMALE_EXTRA_SMALL = "FXS"
    FEMALE_SMALL = "FS"
    FEMALE_MEDIUM = "FM"
    FEMALE_LARGE = "FL"
    FEMALE_EXTRA_LARGE = "FXL"

    SHIRT_SIZE_CHOICES = (
        ('Male', (
            (MALE_SMALL, "Male S"),
            (MALE_MEDIUM, "Male M"),
            (MALE_LARGE, "Male L"),
            (MALE_EXTRA_LARGE, "Male XL")
        )),
        ('Female', (
            (FEMALE_EXTRA_SMALL, "Female XS"),
            (FEMALE_SMALL, "Female S"),
            (FEMALE_MEDIUM, "Female M"),
            (FEMALE_LARGE, "Female L"),
            (FEMALE_EXTRA_LARGE, "Female XL")
        ))
    )

    ASSOCIATE = 'A'
    STAFF = 'S'
    NEITHER = 'N'

    CURTIN_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (ASSOCIATE, 'Associate'),
        (STAFF, 'Staff'),
        (NEITHER, 'Neither/not sure')
    )

    NOTHING = 'NO'
    SOMETHING = 'SO'
    EVERYTHING = 'EV'

    KNOWLEDGE_CHOICES = (
        (NOTHING, 'I know nothing but am keen to learn!'),
        (SOMETHING, 'I know some basics'),
        (EVERYTHING, 'I know a great deal')
    )

    uni = models.CharField(
        max_length = 50,
        null = True,
        blank = True,
        help_text = "University of study"
    )

    uni_study = models.CharField(
        max_length = 256,
        null = True,
        blank = True,
        help_text = "If you're attending university, what are you studying?"
    )

    work = models.CharField(
        max_length = 256,
        null = True,
        blank = True,
        help_text = "If you workwhat do you do?"
    )

    shirt_size = models.CharField(
        max_length = 3,
        blank = True,
        choices = SHIRT_SIZE_CHOICES,
        help_text = "T-shirt size (for uniform)"
    )

    needs_shirt = models.BooleanField(
        default = True,
        help_text = "Does the mentor need to have a shirt provisioned for them?"
    )

    wwcc = models.CharField(
        max_length = 10,
        verbose_name = "WWCC card number",
        blank = True,
        null = True,
        help_text = "WWCC card number (if WWCC card holder)"
    )

    wwcc_receipt = models.CharField(
        max_length = 15,
        verbose_name = "WWCC receipt number",
        blank = True,
        null = True,
        help_text = "WWCC receipt number (if WWCC is processing)"
    )

    curtin_status = models.CharField(
        max_length = 1,
        verbose_name = "Current Curtin HR status",
        choices = CURTIN_STATUS_CHOICES,
        default = NEITHER,
        blank = False,
        help_text = "When possible, we recommend that all CoderDojo mentors are either Curtin University Associates or Staff members."
    )

    curtin_id = models.CharField(
        max_length = 10,
        verbose_name = "Curtin Staff/Associate ID",
        blank = True,
        null = True,
        help_text = "Your Curtin Staff/Associate ID (if applicable)"
    )

    coding_experience = models.CharField(
        max_length = 2,
        blank = False,
        default = NOTHING,
        choices = KNOWLEDGE_CHOICES,
        help_text = "How much programming experience do you have?"
    )

    children_experience = models.CharField(
        max_length = 2,
        blank = False,
        default = NOTHING,
        choices = KNOWLEDGE_CHOICES,
        help_text = "How much experience do you have with children?"
    )

    roles_desired = models.ManyToManyField(Role)

    jobs_desired = models.ManyToManyField('jobs.Job')

    shift_availabilities = models.ManyToManyField(
        'planner.DojoSession',
        help_text = "When are you available?"
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        unique = True
    )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's explain what happens here. When you write :

```
set.exclude( A=arg1, B=arg2 )
```

This translates into the following query :

```
SELECT [...] WHERE NOT (A=arg1 AND B=arg2)
```

In [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28structure%29), ¬(A ∧ B) *(not[A and B])* is actually (¬A ∨ ¬B) *(not[A] OR not[B])*.
Thus what you meant in your query was :

```
SELECT [...] WHERE NOT(A=arg1) OR NOT(B=arg2)
```

Keep this in mind when you write an `exclude`filter that has several parameters.

So, if in your query, you want to exclude the elements that check BOTH criterion (the *intersection* of criterion if you will), the simplest and best way to do it is to **chain exclude filters** :

```
set.exclude(A=arg1).exclude(B=arg2)
```

Queryset operations are *lazy*, meaning roughly that your `exclude` filters will be evaluated at the same time. So two filters won't be "twice the work".

The filter will translate into :

```
SELECT [...] WHERE NOT(A=arg1) AND NOT(B=arg2)
```

Which is exactly what you want !

Writing queries can be sometimes hard, but remember :

- exclude with multiple args translate into : not(A) OR not(B) OR not(C)...
- if you need to exclude items on a conjunction of factors (AND), just make several calls to the `exclude` filter.

---

Now, this is your new query :

```
queryset = Mentor.objects.filter(
    shift__session = session,
    jobs_desired = job
).exclude(
    shift__session = session
).exclude(
    shift__jobs__time = job.time
)
```

If we "flatten" what you are asking, you want :

- records that belong to a session : `filter(shift__session = session)`
- but also... that **don't** belong to that session `.exclude(shift__session = session)`

The generated SQL would be :

```
SELECT [...] WHERE shift__session = session AND [...] AND NOT(shift__session = session)
```

But A ∧ ¬A (*A AND NOT[A]*) is the empty set. So the problem is with the **semantics** of your query.

From your post I read:

> excluding [...] an associated Shift which meets the conditions specified (shift__session = session) AND a (possibly different) associated Shift that meets the second set of criteria

The `filter` you used already guarantees that `shift__session = session`, so you should not put it inside the `exclude` filter.

From what I guess (but tell me if I'm wrong), what you want is :

```
queryset = Mentor.objects.filter(
    shift__session = session,
    jobs_desired = job
).exclude(
    shift__jobs__time = job.time
)
```

Comment: I've read the answer a few times, as far as I can tell I'm making sense of it, but I'm having a hard time relating it back to the actual query I'd require. Again, might be that I've only just started using Django and it's hard for me to map what `exclude()` (or `filter()` for that matter) is doing to actual SQL. I'd appreciate the altered query if possible :) Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Updated with a complete answer !

Comment: Haha, I feel stupid now. Thanks very much. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: It's nothing obvious if you don't know. Tell me if it didn't work. You can also tell me if it did work. :)

Comment: Still getting what appears to be the same issue using two separate `exclude()` calls. I'll read over the OP again to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: I added my models for clarification. By applying your fix (which I believe was to use separate (chained) `exclude()` calls, I experienced different (but still undesired) behaviour...still trying to pinpoint what it is exactly.

Comment: Seen something : do you, by any chance, always get an empty set as an answer ? If so I might have your answer. :)

Comment: Using the new one I do.

Comment: Finally appended the new answer to the previous one, as the problem occurred consequently to what I told you.

Comment: Dammit, still not working. I'm getting the same behaviour as my original query. I have a feeling that the shift__ in the filter() and the shift__ in the exclude() don't necessarily reference the same shift (when traversing a ManyToManyField relationship).

Comment: The reverse relationship might return a set (ForeignKey is a one-to-many relationship). Could you try something like `shift__session__contains` ?

Comment: `Related Field got invalid lookup: contains`

Comment: I'm stupid, `__contains` corresponds to a `LIKE` statement. Try `shift__session__in=session` instead (tests if session is in one of the related objects).

Comment: `'DojoSession' object is not iterable`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to use something like this to get what you're looking for.

```
shifts = Shift.objects.filter(session=session)
excluded_shifts = shifts.filter(jobs__time=job.time)
queryset = Mentor.objects.filter(
    jobs_desired=job
    shift__in=shifts
).exclude(
    shift__in=excluded_shifts
)
```

Don't worry about `shifts` or `excluded_shifts` being executed before the query is run; they're lazy and will only be included as subqueries in the final queryset you're creating.

In pseudo-sql, I think the above will correspond to the following (just going off of past experience here):

```
SELECT *
FROM mentor
LEFT JOIN jobs_desired ON (mentor.id=jobs_desired.mentor_id)
WHERE jobs_desired.id=1
AND shift_id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM shifts
    WHERE session_id=2
)
AND shift_id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM shifts
    LEFT JOIN jobs ON (shifts.id=jobs.session_id)
    WHERE session_id=2
    AND jobs.time='B'
)
```

As you might notice, there's a little bit of double work being performed by the DB here in those two subqueries, but I don't think there's a way to avoid this.

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner! Works perfectly. Thanks a bunch. I'm disappointed in how easy it was, actually :P

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Q functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)?

```
from django.db.models import Q
queryset = Mentor.objects.exclude(
        Q(shift__jobs__time=job.time) & Q(shift__session=session)
    ).filter(jobs_desired=job, shift__session=session)
print str(queryset.query)
```

Which yields SQL like:

```
SELECT "your_project_mentor"."id", "your_project_mentor"."uni", "your_project_mentor"."uni_study", "your_project_mentor"."work", "your_project_mentor"."shirt_size", "your_project_mentor"."needs_shirt", "your_project_mentor"."wwcc", "your_project_mentor"."wwcc_receipt", "your_project_mentor"."curtin_status", "your_project_mentor"."curtin_id", "your_project_mentor"."coding_experience", "your_project_mentor"."children_experience", "your_project_mentor"."user_id" 
  FROM "your_project_mentor" 
  INNER JOIN "your_project_mentor_jobs_desired" 
    ON ( "your_project_mentor"."id" = "your_project_mentor_jobs_desired"."mentor_id" ) 
  INNER JOIN "your_project_shift" 
    ON ( "your_project_mentor"."id" = "your_project_shift"."mentor_id" ) 
  WHERE 
    (NOT 
      ("your_project_mentor"."id" IN 
        (SELECT U1."mentor_id" 
          FROM "your_project_shift" U1 
          INNER JOIN "your_project_shift_jobs" U2 
            ON ( U1."id" = U2."shift_id" ) 
          INNER JOIN "your_project_job" U3 
            ON ( U2."job_id" = U3."id" ) 
          WHERE U3."time" = <job_time> ) 
      AND "your_project_mentor"."id" IN 
        (SELECT U1."mentor_id" 
          FROM "your_project_shift" U1 
          WHERE U1."session_id" = <session_id> )
      ) 
    AND "your_project_mentor_jobs_desired"."job_id" = <job_id>  
    AND "your_project_shift"."session_id" = <session_id> )
```